# How to create your library in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I am using `ride`, I want to know how to create customized library in ROBOT.
Could anyone explain me using basic python program and calling the method of that program in ROBOT?

Comment: start by reading the documentation: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-library-class-or-module

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple example:

A python file name "helloworld.py" contains:

```
class helloworld():
        def __init__(self):
                ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'


        def printHelloWorld(self):
              return    "Hello World"
```

A Robot File

```
*** Settings ***
Library             helloworld.py

*** Test Cases ***
MyTestCase
            ${x}=  Print Hello World
            log to console          ${x}
```

This Prints "**Hello World**" on console.